# Javascript failing when getting a class within a class

Tags: javascript, php, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I'm working on a "worksafe mode" (nudes [NSFW] hidden by default) for my photography website.

index.php contains a series of includes:

```
<?php include 'images/20090820_9616/card.php';?>     
<?php include 'images/20110509_1509/card.php';?>
etc..
```

card.php is identical (except for figure.class) for all SFW images

```
<figure id="<?php echo basename(__DIR__);?>" class="Horizontal Landscape FallColor">
    <a href="<?php echo 'images/'.basename(__DIR)__).'/';?>">
        <img src="<?php echo 'images/'.basename(__DIR__).'/thumbnail.jpg';?>">
    </a>
</figure>
```

card.php for NSFW images is different:

```
<figure id="<?php echo basename(__DIR__);?>" class="NSFW Horizontals">
    <a class="sfw_a" href="#">
        <img class="sfw_img_h" src="images/include/sfw_h.jpg">
    </a>
</figure>
```

Anyway, when someone clicks a "Turn Worksafe Off" button, Javascript should change that second card.php to look basically like the first. I have most of it working:

```
function worksafeOff() {
    var sfw = document.getElementsByClassName('NSFW');
    for (i = 0; i < sfw.length; i++) {
// I. Insert NSFW thumbnails and links
        sfw[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href = '/images/' + sfw[i].id + '/';
        sfw[i].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = '/images/' + sfw[i].id + '/0x.jpg';
// II. Update Class of thumbnails and links to NSFW
        sfw[i].getElementsByClassName('sfw_a')[0].className = 'nsfw_a';
        sfw[i].getElementsByClassName('sfw_img_h')[0].className = 'nsfw_img_h';
        sfw[i].getElementsByClassName('sfw_img_v')[0].className = 'nsfw_img_v';
    }
    document.getElementById('NSFW_deactivateFilter').style.border = '1px solid red';
    document.getElementById('NSFW_deactivateFilter').innerHTML = 'Worksafe Mode: Off';
    document.getElementById('NSFW_deactivateFilter').setAttribute('onClick', 'worksafeOn()');
    document.getElementById('NSFW_deactivateFilter').id = 'NSFW_activateFilter';
}
function worksafeOn() {
    var nsfw = document.getElementsByClassName('NSFW');
    for (i = 0; i < nsfw.length; i++) {
// I. Remove NSFW thumbnails and links
        nsfw[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href = '#';
        nsfw[i].getElementsByClassName('nsfw_img_h')[0].src = 'images/include/sfw_h.jpg';
        nsfw[i].getElementsByClassName('nsfw_img_v')[0].src = 'images/include/sfw_v.jpg';
// II. Update Class of thumbnails and links to SFW
        nsfw[i].getElementsByClassName('nsfw_a')[0].className = 'sfw_a';
        sfw[i].getElementsByClassName('nsfw_img_h')[0].className = 'sfw_img_h';
        sfw[i].getElementsByClassName('nsfw_img_v')[0].className = 'sfw_img_v';
    }
// III. Change "Worksafe Mode: Off" button to "Worksafe Mode: On" button
    document.getElementById('NSFW_activateFilter').style.border = '1px solid black';
    document.getElementById('NSFW_activateFilter').innerHTML = 'Worksafe Mode: On';
    document.getElementById('NSFW_activateFilter').setAttribute('onClick', 'worksafeOff()');
    document.getElementById('NSFW_activateFilter').id = 'NSFW_deactivateFilter';
}
```

Here's [the main jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ktLdd8yv/7/). `gEBTN[0]('a')` and `gEBTN[0]('img')` both work fine. `gEBCN[0]('a.class')` also works perfectly. But attempting `gEBCN[0]('img.class')` fails and hangs the function. In the jsfiddle I've commented out lines 9,10,22,23,26,27 so that you can see there are no other errors.

And here is [a simplified fork](https://jsfiddle.net/b3xh1hhh/) where you can easily see `gEBCN[0]('a.class')` working on line 8 but `gEBCN[0]('img.class')` failing on lines 9 and/or 10.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Barmar Done, sorry it took a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with these two lines:

```
    sfw[i].getElementsByClassName('sfw_img_h')[0].className = 'nsfw_img_h';
    sfw[i].getElementsByClassName('sfw_img_v')[0].className = 'nsfw_img_v';
```

Some elements only have `sfw_img_h` in them, some only have `sfw_img_v` in them. When you try to set the class of the nonexistent element, you get an error and the function exits. You need to test whether the element is there.

```
var imgs = sfw[i].getElementsByClassName('sfw_img_h');
if (imgs.length) {
    imgs[0].className = 'nsfw_img_h';
}
imgs = sfw[i].getElementsByClassName('sfw_img_v');
if (imgs.length) {
    imgs[0].className = 'nsfw_img_v';
}
```

If you ran your code with the console open, you would have seen the error saying that you can't assign to the `className` property of `undefined`.

Comment: I saw that error but don't understand it because what you describe isn't how `gEBCN` is supposed to work. It's supposed to sort of be its own `if` statement: if it doesn't find the `className` specified, it's just supposed to do nothing and move on.

And in the line immediately before those two (`sfw[i].getElementsByClassName('sfw_a')[0].className = 'nsfw_a';`) that's exactly what it does with an `a` element. It's only on the `img` elements that it fails. See [this fork](https://jsfiddle.net/b3xh1hhh) to confirm that.

So your workaround works but why it's necessary remains a mystery.

Comment: I don't see any way that "its own `if` statement` could be possible. `gEBCN` returns a `NodeList`, `[0]` accesses an element of the list. If the list is empty, that returns undefined and `.className` is an error. The line before works because there's always a `swf_a` element, so it never returns an empty `NodeList`.

Comment: Hmmm, okay, I think I'm understanding `gEBCN` more now. I changed it so that there was only one `sfw_a` element and it did indeed fail.

Maybe I'm not understanding `for` loops, though. `sfw.length` is 3, so the loop should run three times, right? But there are only 2 `sfw_a` elements, so the statement "the `sfw_a` line works because there's always another `sfw_a` element" shouldn't be true for all the runs.

Comment: `sfw.length` should be only 2, because there are only two `class="NSFW"` elements. The `for` loop should run with `i = 0` and `i = 1`.

Comment: BTW, you should always use a local variable for the `for` loop index. I've seen many bugs due to using `i` as a global variable in multiple functions that call each other.

Comment: Oops I thought I'd defined `sfw` as `gEBTN('figure')` which would've been 3, but it's `gEBCN('NSFW')`. Okay thanks it makes sense now. And interesting tip about the global variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) function. This will allow you to grab the element using element, class or id:

`sfw[i].querySelector('.sfw_img_h')[0].className = 'nsfw_img_h';`

Comment: If `getElementsByClassName()` can't find the elements, why would `querySelector()` do better? Also, you don't need to use `[0]` with `querySelector`, it just returns the first element found -- only `querySelectorAll` returns a list.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem at hand but it did lead me to research the `qS` and `qSA` functions and discover they're a better option for a lot of things. So thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not add a data-nsfw-src and data-sfw-src to the NSFW images? Then you can use that attribute instead of id and vice versa.

Like suggested by @pabs123, use querySelector or querySelectorAll: (**untested**)

```
var nsfw_images = document.querySelectorAll('[data-nsfw-src]');
for(var i in nsfw_images) {
    nsfw_images[i].src = nsfw_images[i].getAttribute('data-sfw-src');
}
```

You could also add both the NSFW and SFW image, change a global container class(like document.documentElement), and use styling to show/hide the proper image. Easier then switching img src.

```
.hide-nsfw img.nsfw, .show-nsfw img.sfw {display:none}
```